# Create an AMI using ansible ec2_ami module and grab snapshot_id(s) from registered variable

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

    - name: Read Variables
      include_vars:
        file: variables.yml


    - name: Create AMI
      ec2_ami:
        aws_access_key: "{{ ACCESS_KEY }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ SECRET_KEY }}"
        region: "{{ AWS_REGION }}"
        delete_snapshot: yes
        instance_id: "{{ ID_INSTANCE }}"
        name: "{{ SUFFIX_BACKUP }}-{{ NAME_BACKUP }}"
        wait: yes
        description: "{{ DESCR }}"
        tags:
          project: project1
      register: ami_data
```

Example content of "ami_data" variable:

```
    "msg": {
        "architecture": "x86_64", 
        "block_device_mapping": {
            "/dev/sda1": {
                "delete_on_termination": true, 
                "encrypted": false, 
                "size": 30, 
                "snapshot_id": "snap-0e95eac98734af1d1", 
                "volume_type": "gp2"
            }
        }, 
        "changed": false, 
        "creationDate": "2017-12-13T17:02:47.000Z", 
        "description": "descripition", 
        "failed": false, 
        "hypervisor": "xen", 
        "image_id": "ami-XXXXXX", 
        "is_public": false, 
        "launch_permissions": {}, 
        "location": "457841571138/MYAMINAME", 
        "msg": "AMI not updated", 
        "name": "MYAMINAME", 
        "ownerId": "XXXXXXXXXX", 
        "platform": null, 
        "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
        "root_device_type": "ebs", 
        "state": "available", 
        "tags": {
            "project": "project1", 
        }, 
        "virtualization_type": "hvm"
    }
}
```

And now I want to grab the "snapshot_id" that was registered on "ami_data" variable for every disk on it. I have tried the following debug tasks using "msg" to show the value(s) of "snapshot_id" but non of them worked. What I'm doing wrong?

```
- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping[*].snapshot_id }}"

- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping[/dev/sda1].snapshot_id }}"

- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping./dev/sda1.snapshot_id }}"

- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping.[*].snapshot_id }}"
```

This one works:

```
- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping }}"
```

And give me the following:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "/dev/sda1": {
            "delete_on_termination": true, 
            "encrypted": false, 
            "size": 30, 
            "snapshot_id": "snap-0ea846d9aca82b51f", 
            "volume_type": "gp2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with the ami_data.block_device_mapping you have to iterate with the list and after search under the map with the key name of the element (snapshot_id in this case):

```
  - debug:
      msg: {{ item }}
    with_items: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping|map(attribute='snapshot_id')|list}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close. Use square brackets but use quotes to specify literals:

```
- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping['/dev/sda1'].snapshot_id }}"
```

or using variables:

```
- name: Show data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping[item].snapshot_id }}"
  with_items: "{{ ami_data.block_device_mapping }}"
```